# Cannot see parameter value in Android Studio when breakpoint is in first line of a method

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I am just switching from Eclipse to Android Studio and found this weird behavior. When I add a breakpoint in the first line of a method, I cannot see the parameter values. The only thing I can see then is the `this` reference. I either have to make one debug step or set the breakpoint to a line after the first one to see the parameter values.

Anyone else has this problem or knows what's going wrong here?

Comment: possibly your code and what is running are not in sync, and there is an extra line somewhere. Try to clean, install and run again.

Comment: Yea, i did that multiple times. I cleaned the project and restarted the IDE. Still the same...

Comment: I'm having the same problem across multiple projects.

Comment: I have the same problem. It has nothing to do with synchronization.

Comment: How do we report it? I couldn't find an obvious link on Android Tools projects site.

Comment: Bug reported here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=119564&thanks=119564&ts=1422496187

Comment: do u use paramaters final in your method parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution provided by Google [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=119564) is to upgrade the Android Studio Gradle plugin to v1.0.1

Answer (score 39):

Try turning off your jacoco test coverage off for the debug build in your build.gradle file:

```
debug {
    ...
    testCoverageEnabled false
}
```

This completely fixed the issue for me where upgrading the gradle plugin did not.

Comment: This worked for me.  BTW, this snippet should be in the app build script, mine is in the "android" section of that script. The android issue tracker includes issue [177480](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177480&q=debug%20arguments&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) which includes this answer, as well as some other recommendations on the topic.

Comment: Don't know why, but this seems to have worked for me too.  So the problem is jacoco?

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, am using gradle plugin 2.0.0 and still had this issue. This one fixed it for me.

Comment: Worked for me. Why is this happening though... I shouldn't have to turn off jacoco to debug -.-

Answer (score 7):

A good solution until [AOSP Issue #123771](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=123771) is solved, is to use the snippet provided by [Stuart](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=123771#c8) in the comments section:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        [...]
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }
    release {
        [...]
    }
    debuggable.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
    debuggable {
        testCoverageEnabled false
    }
}
```

This way you can both keep your test coverage reports in your debug build and have a way of stepping through code seeing your local variables.

Comment: This didn't work for me (at least not in espresso tests)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have in my gradle file:

```
debug {
    ...
    testCoverageEnabled true
}
```

but **had the same issue on Android Studio 2.2**. Solution that helped me to resolve issue:

1. Disable *Instant Run* in IDEA Settings.
2. Re-build project.
3. Enable *Instant Run*.

Comment: I had Instant Run disabled because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618803/android-app-crashes-when-launched-in-debug-mode and then breakpoints worked again after reenabling.

Answer (score 1):

If your build uses the [jack toolchain](https://source.android.com/source/jack.html) this can be the source of the problem. In my case, disabling jack solves the problem:

```
buildTypes {
...
    debug {
        jackOptions {
            enabled false
        }
    }
}
```

Note: 1.8 source compatibility requires jack!

Answer (score 1):

I got sick of toggling `testCoverageEnabled` when I wanted to debug so set up a project property to disable it when run from Android Studio, but default to enabled when run from command line with no options such as on a build box.

```
// Default to true, set -PtestCoverageEnabled=false in IDE compiler command-line options
def isTestCoverageEnabled = { ->
    def enabled = project.hasProperty('testCoverageEnabled') ? testCoverageEnabled.toBoolean() : true
    println "testCoverageEnabled = " + (enabled ? "true" : "false")
    return enabled
}

android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled isTestCoverageEnabled()
        }
    }
}
```

To set the property in the IDE add the command-line option `-PtestCoverageEnabled=false`

Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Command-line Options

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when trying to debug an app that was previously installed using an APK and not from Android Studio itself. Fixed it by uninstalling the app and re-run the debug.

Answer (score 0):

Following configuration worked for me for buildType release.

buildTypes {

release{

testCoverageEnabled = false

debuggable true

minifyEnabled false

shrinkResources false

}