# Android app crashes when launched in debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-debug, android-debugging

When I run in **debug** mode the app crashes, but when I just run it normally it works.
I think the problem happens when the debugger is attached.

Log:

```
A/art: art/runtime/jdwp/jdwp_event.cc:661] Check failed: Thread::Current() != GetDebugThread() (Thread::Current()=0x7f44a18400, GetDebugThread()=0x7f44a18400) Expected event thread
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Runtime aborting...
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Aborting thread:
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "JDWP" prio=5 tid=4 WaitingForDebuggerSend
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c60280 self=0x7f44a18400
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=24137 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f4b904450
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 132066712 16401043 106 ) utm=9 stm=2 core=3 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0x7f4b80a000-0x7f4b80c000 stackSize=1005KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 000000000047e2cc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+220)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 000000000047e2c8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+216)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0000000000452434  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+480)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 00000000004403ac  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+56)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 0000000000440228  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+668)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 0000000000433bfc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+148)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00000000000e597c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+1592)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 00000000002f8458  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEm+624)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 00000000002f7b1c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEm+248)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 00000000002fcb08  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1380)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 0000000000124a9c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcmNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+804)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 0000000000381d04  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL25DexFile_defineClassNativeEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP8_jstringP8_jobjectS7_S7_+344)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 00000000001dd40c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (???)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native method)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:296)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:289)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:418)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:367)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:367)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
```

Comment: I dont know what happend, but now work it. Magic!!!

Comment: I ran into the same problem and it was complete BS. Even restarting the emulator did not help. After removing a bunch of code and then readding it in one block at a time, I arrived back to the original code and the problem was gone. I have a feeling the class object just needed to be rebuilt. A compile went wrong. I'm guessing a project "clean" probably would have fixed it.

Comment: Almost 3 years later, this bug is still present.

Answer (score 330, accepted):

For me, it occurred when I have a breakpoint in a nested function. In my case, it was within `Runnable.run() {}`. Not sure if it happens in other nested functions.

Example:

```
public class TouchEvent {
    public boolean HandleEvent(MotionEvent Event) {
        new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {
            int i=5;
            i++;
        }};
    }
}
```

If there is a breakpoint on any line inside the run() func, it crashes with the error `A/art: art/runtime/jdwp/jdwp_event.cc:661] Check failed: Thread::Current() != GetDebugThread() (Thread::Current()=0x########, GetDebugThread()=0x########) Expected event thread` .

This error occurs the first time the class is encountered, NOT when the breakpoint is hit. So it occurred for me when I stepped into a line that had `new TouchEvent();`, before any of the TouchEvent's code was run (before the constructor).

The solution is to remove the break point (and put it elsewhere).

**Edit:**

Forgot to mention, it seems to be tied to API25, but has been reported for API26 and API27 too.

**Edit:**

Another solution is to disabled **Instant Run**, but please give [@toobsco42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502671/toobsco42) credit for that below.

Comment: This has been reported on code.google.com and I am working on getting it fixed there. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227513

Comment: I have sdk 23 and build tools 25.0.1 - same problem. Removing the breakpoints fixes this.

Comment: You can also remove the breakpoint, press Debug, then once the app is running OK, add it back in to the spot you wanted. Works ok then, just remember to remove it before you restart.

Comment: Same happening to me setting a breakpoint in a `underscore-java` nested `filter` `Predicate` function on Android Studio 2.2.3

Comment: I switched emulators and problem went away - switched back to original emulator and problem came back.  Once the problem appears only way to overcome it (besides clearing all breakpoints - no thanks) is to disable Instant Run.  Re-enabling Instant Run on the problem emulator brings the problem back.

Comment: The issue is a mix of breakpoints in other threads on 7.1.1 with instant run on. So change any of the above 3 and it will stop crashing.

Comment: I just had to outright disable Instant Run. Even starting the app in debug mode without breakpoints and then adding them later, crashes the app. With Instant Run disabled, it works just fine. My android `buildToolsVersion` is `25.0.3` and gradle-wrapper version is `2.3.3`.

Comment: I think problem may be created when there are method breakpoints and line breakpoints

Comment: I can confirm this on API 26 and buildToolsVersion `26.0.2` as well.

Comment: Agreed - I ran into this issue with API 26/buildToolsVersion 26.0.2!

Comment: @cometfish That seems very tedious though.

Comment: Arggh - wasted so much time on this - thank you for this post !

Answer (score 187):

In my case i had to disable Instant Run.  It seems like Instant Run has all sorts of side effects and this can be one of them.

Comment: Note, in Android Studio, the is under File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run.

Comment: That was an hour of my life I'll never see again

Comment: Working on multiple machines, with Google constantly reapplying instant run, I'd need it to make me roughly 4216% more efficient when it finally works to remotely come close to getting my lost time back.

Comment: thankss so damn much. should be ticked as answer ;) this ugly feature gives a you a five cent and wastes you a hundred dollars :))

Comment: This was *the* answer for me.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly.. what's this feature used for anyways? looks like it's just a bloat feature to me. btw this is still affecting Android O and latest android studio RC1

Comment: Ahhw, Worked, This should be the acceptable answer (API 25)

Comment: Perfect! Simple solution

Comment: This problem seems still to exist. Thank you very much for the workaround.

Comment: InstantRun is a shame. I always turn it off these years. It has many side effects. Wasted much time, then realized that InstantRun added bugs.

Comment: where is "Instant Run" on Android Studio 4.0 ?

Answer (score 50):

Problem is related with Android version 7.x, i removed all the breakpoints in nested functions and it worked, tested with Android version 6.0 too, and it is working without problem.

According to google developers team response, it was fixed on 12/1/2016 and will be applied in next release.

Comment: tried all possible, above comment helped! thanks a lot!

Comment: It worked, this should be accepted answer. Thanks ! Also, you can remove Instant Run as a another solution

Comment: It would be nice if a link was attached to support this ;) "According to google developers team response, it was fixed on 12/1/2016 and will be applied in next release."

Comment: Probably was an email response, still getting this bug today and had to remove breakpoints

Comment: Android 7.1.1 is still the version of Android running on the Pixelbook. I get this all the time developing in Android Studio on the Pixelbook!

Answer (score 21):

I removed all the breakpoints and it worked, tested with Emulator Pixel API 25.

To remove all breakpoints:

- Go to Debugger option.
- Click on red icon which is below to stop debug.
- You will see a window there you can remove all breakpoints.

See more in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42478994/5749462

Answer (score 16):

This is due to some problem with debug points. Remove all the debug points and then it should work.

Comment: You can use the shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+F8 to unmark all breakpoints easily.

Comment: This shortcut doesn't work all the time depending your OS and keyboard settings

Answer (score 8):

Its really weird, i disabled Instant Run and the problem solved itself.

Comment: Yes, instant run on devices below Android 7.0 may cause this issue quite easily

Answer (score 4):

My issue was that I had a breakpoint at import statement

Comment: And ran into this for like third time... Basically, any breakpoint sometimes can cause this, thus the solution may be just to remove all / recent breakpoints

Answer (score 4):

My app also crashed only when in debug mode. As for 3.5 version - "Instant Run" was replaced with "Apply Changes", so I could not disable it. My solution was to launch the app normally (with the green arrow), navigate just after the place it used to crash and then to attach the debugger to it:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

In the window 5 : Debug, Use the button "View Breakpoints"

[image]

UnSelectAll of them

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Delete All debug points on my application works fine
you can use ctrl+shift+f6  to remove all debug points

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same issue but my breakpoint was the first line in the nested function so how to move it elsewhere?

I created a temporary private method and made an invocation of that method the first thing in the function and then I set the breakpoint in that method.

When I finished debugging I removed the method and its invocation.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is trying to **find another device or emulator** (thanks AVD Manager we have a choice) that will work as charm without workarounds

Answer (score 0):

Removing breakpoint from Runable.run() solved the issue for me. I was able to use breakpoints at runtime inside Runable.run(). But not at compile time

Answer (score 0):

it is a long shot but for me, when I have an import statement that isn't being used, and that import has code that runs network calls, it crashed for me but when removing it, the code was able to debug normally.

Answer (score 0):

Starting crashing only when starting with debugger.  Restarted Android Studio 2.3.2...kept crashing. Runs fine in Run mode.  I put in a Log.d() right after onCreate...and it cleared up the problem!  Go figure!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

for anyone who still have the crashing problem after the above solutions, here's what i have done to fix it on my m1 mac air.

Make sure the select 'wait for debugger' in developer options, and go through other options as well, to make sure they are what you want them to be.