# Android debug strange errors

Tags: java, android, debugging

I have client - server app on android

When I try to run it as normal there is no errors. But if I try to debug it there appeared wall of errors. I dont even know what about and what to look for. And what is wrong.

This is not all errors I cut it in half because it is too long.

Errors:

```
A/art: art/runtime/jdwp/jdwp_event.cc:661] Check failed: Thread::Current() != GetDebugThread() (Thread::Current()=0xb188a400, GetDebugThread()=0xb188a400) Expected event thread
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Runtime aborting...
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Aborting thread:
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "JDWP" prio=5 tid=4 WaitingForDebuggerSend
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cde9d0 self=0xb188a400
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=3751 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaced2920
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=2 core=1 HZ=100
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xacdd6000-0xacdd8000 stackSize=1014KB
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 00572f1e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+238)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0053f30e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BaA/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0053c30b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+75)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 00527f13  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+67)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 00527ce7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+615)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 0051822b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+155)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0011a5b3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD1Ev+1747)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 0039b74d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEy+733)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0039acf3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEy+211)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 003a0ec9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1705)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 001c2a85  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+53)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 001689fc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+1116)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 001683e9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+1865)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #13 pc 0016979b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+1163)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #14 pc 005a7a7a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache12ResolveClassEPKcPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderE+186)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #15 pc 005a742d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache4FromEPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEPKcb+701)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #16 pc 005a70fd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache14FromDescriptorEPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEPKcb+77)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #17 pc 005862ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier26ResolveClassAndCheckAccessEj+173)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #18 pc 0058840f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier25CodeFlowVerifyInstructionEPj+6463)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #19 pc 00585f96  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier20CodeFlowVerifyMethodEv+358)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #20 pc 00581c9d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier14VerifyCodeFlowEv+973)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #21 pc 0057da56  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier6VerifyEv+854)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #22 pc 0057c742  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier12VerifyMethodEPNS_6ThreadEjPKNS_7DexFileENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS7_INS8_11ClassLoaderEEEPKNS4_8ClassDefEPKNS4_8CodeItemEPNS_9ArtMethodEjPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEbPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSO_11char_traitsIcEENSO_9allocatorIcEEEE+226)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #23 pc 0057c1c7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier13VerifyMethodsILb0EEENS1_11FailureDataEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_11ClassLinkerEPKNS_7DexFileEPKNS8_8ClassDefEPNS_21ClassDataItemIteratorENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENSG_INSH_11ClassLoaderEEEPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEbPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSP_11char_traitsIcEENSP_9allocatorIcEEEE+791)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #24 pc 0057b1f9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFileENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS7_INS8_11ClassLoaderEEEPKNS4_8ClassDefEPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSJ_11char_traitsIcEENSJ_9allocatorIcEEEE+921)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #25 pc 0057a4b9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror5ClassEPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSA_11char_traitsIcEENSA_9allocatorIcEEEE+841)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #26 pc 00174386  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEENS_11LogSeverityE+2102)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #27 pc 0017a406  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker15InitializeClassEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEEbb+326)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #28 pc 00158dde  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker17EnsureInitializedEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEEbb+222)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #29 pc 001b60da  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL17GetFieldValueImplEyyyPNS_4JDWP9ExpandBufEb+1866)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #30 pc 001b667e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg19GetStaticFieldValueEyyPNS_4JDWP9ExpandBufE+78)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #31 pc 003a4c5d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWPL12RT_GetValuesEPNS0_9JdwpStateEPNS0_7RequestEPNS0_9ExpandBufE+141)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #32 pc 003a2ea4  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState14ProcessRequestEPNS0_7RequestEPNS0_9ExpandBufEPb+1044)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #33 pc 003ab570  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState12HandlePacketEv+192)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #34 pc 00678df3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP12JdwpAdbState15ProcessIncomingEv+1139)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #35 pc 003ab9d1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState3RunEv+593)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #36 pc 003aae50  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWPL15StartJdwpThreadEPv+48)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #37 pc 00075082  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #38 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #39 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
    A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Dumping all threads without appropriate 

locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] All threads:
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] DALVIK THREADS (16):
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "JDWP" prio=5 tid=4 Runnable
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cde9d0 self=0xb188a400
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=3751 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaced2920
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4 stm=4 core=0 HZ=100
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xacdd6000-0xacdd8000 stackSize=1014KB
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 00572f1e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+238)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0053f30e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+526)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0053c30b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+75)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0055befb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+1115)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 005521be  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureE+590)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 00551d32  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEb+962)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00528168  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState14DumpAllThreadsERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+424)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 00527eb6  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+1078)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0051822b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+155)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 0011a5b3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD1Ev+1747)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 0039b74d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEy+733)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 0039acf3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEy+211)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 003a0ec9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1705)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #13 pc 001c2a85  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+53)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #14 pc 001689fc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+1116)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #15 pc 001683e9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+1865)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #16 pc 0016979b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+1163)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #17 pc 005a7a7a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache12ResolveClassEPKcPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderE+186)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #18 pc 005a742d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache4FromEPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEPKcb+701)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #19 pc 005a70fd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache14FromDescriptorEPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEPKcb+77)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #20 pc 005862ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier26ResolveClassAndCheckAccessEj+173)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #21 pc 0058840f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier25CodeFlowVerifyInstructionEPj+6463)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #22 pc 00585f96  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier20CodeFlowVerifyMethodEv+358)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #23 pc 00581c9d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier14VerifyCodeFlowEv+973)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #24 pc 0057da56  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier6VerifyEv+854)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #25 pc 0057c742  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier12VerifyMethodEPNS_6ThreadEjPKNS_7DexFileENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS7_INS8_11ClassLoaderEEEPKNS4_8ClassDefEPKNS4_8CodeItemEPNS_9ArtMethodEjPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEbPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSO_11char_traitsIcEENSO_9allocatorIcEEEE+226)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #26 pc 0057c1c7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier13VerifyMethodsILb0EEENS1_11FailureDataEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_11ClassLinkerEPKNS_7DexFileEPKNS8_8ClassDefEPNS_21ClassDataItemIteratorENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENSG_INSH_11ClassLoaderEEEPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEbPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSP_11char_traitsIcEENSP_9allocatorIcEEEE+791)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #27 pc 0057b1f9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFileENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS7_INS8_11ClassLoaderEEEPKNS4_8ClassDefEPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSJ_11char_traitsIcEENSJ_9allocatorIcEEEE+921)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #28 pc 0057a4b9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror5ClassEPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSA_11char_traitsIcEENSA_9allocatorIcEEEE+841)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #29 pc 00174386  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEENS_11LogSeverityE+2102)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #30 pc 0017a406  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker15InitializeClassEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEEbb+326)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #31 pc 00158dde  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker17EnsureInitializedEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEEbb+222)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #32 pc 001b60da  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL17GetFieldValueImplEyyyPNS_4JDWP9ExpandBufEb+1866)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #33 pc 001b667e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg19GetStaticFieldValueEyyPNS_4JDWP9ExpandBufE+78)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #34 pc 003a4c5d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWPL12RT_GetValuesEPNS0_9JdwpStateEPNS0_7RequestEPNS0_9ExpandBufE+141)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #35 pc 003a2ea4  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState14ProcessRequestEPNS0_7RequestEPNS0_9ExpandBufEPb+1044)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #36 pc 003ab570  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState12HandlePacketEv+192)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #37 pc 00678df3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP12JdwpAdbState15ProcessIncomingEv+1139)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #38 pc 003ab9d1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState3RunEv+593)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #39 pc 003aae50  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWPL15StartJdwpThreadEPv+48)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #40 pc 00075082  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #41 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #42 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Suspended
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=2 dsCount=1 obj=0x74934f60 self=0xadc8b400
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=3744 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb1fff534
        A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=17 stm=18 core=1 HZ=100
```

Comment: You may wish to have a look at [Crash android app when debug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618803/crash-android-app-when-debug). Perhaps due to a breakpoint within a Runnable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like MikeT said.

This was a problem with breakpoints. I made breakpoint in every line and some of them were create wrong. When I delete it it was fine.

Comment: This worked for me - I deleted all breakpoints in my app and re-ran it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you give breakpoint on static member function or function so it gives error and suddenly crash the app

[image]