# Seemingly random crash somewhere deep inside ART

Tags: android, art-runtime

I'm getting a crash, without useful logcat. The useless error dump mentions different java source lines every time. (mostly in a JSONObject.put, but it does vary). This happens somewhere in `onHandleIntent` in an `IntentService`...

```
A/art: art/runtime/jdwp/jdwp_event.cc:681] Check failed: threadId != 0u (threadId=0, 0u=0) 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Runtime aborting...
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Aborting thread:
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 WaitingForDebuggerSend (still starting up)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0x7413c16000
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=19272 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x741ad02450
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 326115573 6002657 230 ) utm=26 stm=5 core=1 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0x741ac04000-0x741ac06000 stackSize=1021KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 000000000047e090  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+220)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 000000000047e08c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+216)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 00000000004521f8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+480)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0000000000440170  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+56)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 000000000043ffec  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+668)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 0000000000433998  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+148)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00000000000e5a7c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+1592)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 00000000002f8adc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState19SetWaitForJdwpTokenEm+1000)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 00000000002f7ffc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEm+124)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 00000000002f78b4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEm+248)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 00000000002fc8a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1380)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 0000000000124b9c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcmNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+804)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 00000000001246dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcmNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+1484)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #13 pc 000000000012566c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+944)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #14 pc 000000000010ccb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11ResolveTypeERKNS_7DexFileEtNS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS4_INS5_11ClassLoaderEEE+200)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #15 pc 000000000018fec8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder13ResolveMethodEtNS_10InvokeTypeE+1544)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #16 pc 00000000001905ac  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder11BuildInvokeERKNS_11InstructionEjjjbPjj+768)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #17 pc 000000000018b894  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder21ProcessDexInstructionERKNS_11InstructionEj+896)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #18 pc 000000000018ad48  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder5BuildEv+1600)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #19 pc 0000000000163b14  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art13HGraphBuilder10BuildGraphEv+136)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #20 pc 00000000001c26d8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art18OptimizingCompiler10TryCompileEPNS_14ArenaAllocatorEPNS_19CodeVectorAllocatorEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEjNS_10InvokeTypeEtjP8_jobjectRKS5_NS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+3280)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #21 pc 00000000001c4b74  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art18OptimizingCompiler10JitCompileEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_3jit12JitCodeCacheEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+472)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #22 pc 0000000000153014  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art3jit11JitCompiler13CompileMethodEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+284)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #23 pc 000000000030fc4c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit3Jit13CompileMethodEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadEb+492)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #24 pc 0000000000311b38  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit14JitCompileTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+656)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #25 pc 000000000046afa8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+88)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #26 pc 000000000046a8f0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+116)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #27 pc 00000000000686bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+208)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #28 pc 000000000001da7c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] All threads:
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] DALVIK THREADS (15):
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 Runnable (still starting up)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0x7413c16000
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=19272 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x741ad02450
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 350997605 6193803 232 ) utm=27 stm=7 core=4 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0x741ac04000-0x741ac06000 stackSize=1021KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 000000000047e090  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+220)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 000000000047e08c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+216)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 00000000004521f8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+480)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0000000000469d7c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+832)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 0000000000461f64  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureE+476)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 0000000000461b54  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEb+848)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 000000000043ffa0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+592)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 0000000000433998  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+148)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 00000000000e5a7c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+1592)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 00000000002f8adc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState19SetWaitForJdwpTokenEm+1000)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 00000000002f7ffc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEm+124)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 00000000002f78b4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEm+248)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 00000000002fc8a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1380)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #13 pc 0000000000124b9c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcmNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+804)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #14 pc 00000000001246dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcmNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+1484)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #15 pc 000000000012566c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+944)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #16 pc 000000000010ccb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11ResolveTypeERKNS_7DexFileEtNS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS4_INS5_11ClassLoaderEEE+200)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #17 pc 000000000018fec8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder13ResolveMethodEtNS_10InvokeTypeE+1544)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #18 pc 00000000001905ac  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder11BuildInvokeERKNS_11InstructionEjjjbPjj+768)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #19 pc 000000000018b894  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder21ProcessDexInstructionERKNS_11InstructionEj+896)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #20 pc 000000000018ad48  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder5BuildEv+1600)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #21 pc 0000000000163b14  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art13HGraphBuilder10BuildGraphEv+136)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #22 pc 00000000001c26d8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art18OptimizingCompiler10TryCompileEPNS_14ArenaAllocatorEPNS_19CodeVectorAllocatorEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEjNS_10InvokeTypeEtjP8_jobjectRKS5_NS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+3280)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #23 pc 00000000001c4b74  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art18OptimizingCompiler10JitCompileEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_3jit12JitCodeCacheEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+472)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #24 pc 0000000000153014  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art3jit11JitCompiler13CompileMethodEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+284)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #25 pc 000000000030fc4c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit3Jit13CompileMethodEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadEb+492)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #26 pc 0000000000311b38  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit14JitCompileTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+656)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #27 pc 000000000046afa8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+88)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #28 pc 000000000046a8f0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+116)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #29 pc 00000000000686bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+208)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #30 pc 000000000001da7c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x74de6a88 self=0x741b695a00
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=19267 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x741f654a98
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 657667230 66328120 455 ) utm=57 stm=7 core=5 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0x7ff8188000-0x7ff818a000 stackSize=8MB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: __switch_to+0x8c/0x98
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_epoll_wait+0x2d0/0x358
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_epoll_pwait+0xc8/0x160
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: cpu_switch_to+0x48/0x4c
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 000000000006aaf4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 000000000001e1a4  /system/lib64/libc.so (epoll_pwait+64)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0000000000018010  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+156)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0000000000017eb4  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+60)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 00000000000f0670  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+48)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 000000000089e6d0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+140)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "IntentService[SyncService]" prio=5 tid=15 Runnable
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d08ca0 self=0x74013e9000
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=19564 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x73fc1a0450
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 880255679 2078694 80 ) utm=78 stm=8 core=6 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0x73fc09e000-0x73fc0a0000 stackSize=1037KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 000000000047e090  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+220)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 000000000047e08c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+216)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 00000000004521f8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+480)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0000000000469d7c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+832)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 000000000045315c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread21RunCheckpointFunctionEv+192)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 00000000002b8040  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+63252)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0000000000262890  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+484)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 000000000026851c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+184)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 000000000028975c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+568)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 00000000002a6c24  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL20DoInvokeVirtualQuickILb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+452)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 00000000002b5dd8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+54444)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 0000000000262890  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+484)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 000000000026851c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+184)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #13 pc 000000000028975c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+568)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #14 pc 00000000002b9104  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE2ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+612)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #15 pc 00000000002b5190  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+51300)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #16 pc 0000000000262890  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+484)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #17 pc 000000000026851c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+184)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #18 pc 000000000028975c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+568)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #19 pc 00000000002b9104  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE2ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+612)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #20 pc 00000000002b5190  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+51300)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #21 pc 0000000000262890  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+484)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #22 pc 000000000026851c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+184)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #23 pc 000000000028975c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+568)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #24 pc 00000000002b9104  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE2ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+612)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #25 pc 00000000002b5190  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+51300)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #26 pc 0000000000262890  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+484)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #27 pc 000000000026851c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+184)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #28 pc 000000000028975c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+568)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #29 pc 00000000002bc300  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE0ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+356)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #30 pc 00000000002b7870  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+61252)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #31 pc 0000000000262890  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+484)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #32 pc 000000000054d9e4  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+832)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #33 pc 00000000000dbe2c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #34 pc 00000000000d2734  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #35 pc 00000000000df400  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+208)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #36 pc 000000000042d334  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+108)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #37 pc 000000000042e638  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+372)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #38 pc 000000000044dfd8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+1100)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #39 pc 00000000000686bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+208)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #40 pc 000000000001da7c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at nz.co.digitalstock.vibration_action_vfib.database.VibrationFrame.getTimestamp(VibrationFrame.java:64)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at nz.co.digitalstock.vibration_action_vfib.services.SyncService.onHandleIntent(SyncService.java:76)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:68)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
{a bit missing for length}
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8616', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: I'm getting something very similar. Crash is sporadic but can generally be created within a few minutes of use. Logcat info looks almost same as yours.

Comment: I wish I could help you but I can't even remember what I did to fix it... but I do remember that I never figured out exactly why I was getting the crash.

Comment: I think I have "fixed" the issue. My app uses firebase, which essentially means that I have callback code that will come in on threads other than the UI Thread. And i was doing some ui operations on those callbacks. So I pushed all the callback code to execute on the UI thread and the problem doesn't seem to occur any more.

Comment: Sounds about right. I think my issue was relating to threading also, and I just changed round the entire structure of what I was doing and the issue went away.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618803/android-app-crashes-when-launched-in-debug-mode

Comment: Possibly this (maybe patched?) Google bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37126388

Comment: I was getting a vary similar crash and turning off some breakpoints helped.