# App crash only in debug mode

Tags: android, debugging, firebase, crash

I am new to programming, and are trying to make an android app. The last few days I have really had trouble using the debugger. The app work just fine in normal run mode. 
The app are connected to firebase, and all data is saved there. If i try to log in as a student in debug mode the app crash rights away. If i log in as a professor i get to the mainpage, but if i click the next button i'll be thrown back to the login page, and it changes to run mode. 
I have really none idea what the problem is, but there is something about the debugger and firebase?

I dont know where i shall start to look in the error message i get, so i just post everything and hope someone knows this problem or could tell me where in the errorcode i shall look for the solution. Thanks! I post some of the error here:

```
                                        [ 03-26 11:07:15.981  1253: 1253 W/         ]
                                        debuggerd: resuming target 890
03-26 11:07:15.982 1574-1592/system_process I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_08 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
03-26 11:07:16.068 1574-2194/system_process D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 5
03-26 11:07:16.073 1574-1618/system_process W/InputDispatcher: channel '3bb91ba com.example.anna.eduback2/com.example.anna.eduback2.views.Login.LoginActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
03-26 11:07:16.074 1574-1618/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '3bb91ba com.example.anna.eduback2/com.example.anna.eduback2.views.Login.LoginActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-26 11:07:16.075 1574-1618/system_process W/InputDispatcher: channel '4df46b1 com.example.anna.eduback2/com.example.anna.eduback2.views.Mains.MainActivityProfessor (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
03-26 11:07:16.076 1574-1618/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '4df46b1 com.example.anna.eduback2/com.example.anna.eduback2.views.Mains.MainActivityProfessor (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-26 11:07:16.077 1302-1302/? I/Zygote: Process 890 exited due to signal (6)
03-26 11:07:16.122 1574-1986/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.anna.eduback2/.views.Subject.SubjectViewActivity
03-26 11:07:16.185 1574-2193/system_process I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{4df46b1 u0 com.example.anna.eduback2/com.example.anna.eduback2.views.Mains.MainActivityProfessor}
03-26 11:07:16.186 1574-2193/system_process W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '4df46b1 com.example.anna.eduback2/com.example.anna.eduback2.views.Mains.MainActivityProfessor (server)'
03-26 11:07:16.191 1574-2084/system_process I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{3bb91ba u0 com.example.anna.eduback2/com.example.anna.eduback2.views.Login.LoginActivity}
03-26 11:07:16.192 1574-2084/system_process W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '3bb91ba com.example.anna.eduback2/com.example.anna.eduback2.views.Login.LoginActivity (server)'
03-26 11:07:16.211 1574-1986/system_process W/ActivityManager: Exception thrown during pause
                                                               android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
                                                                   at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:785)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:1141)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3523)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3359)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1855)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.handleAppCrashLocked(AppErrors.java:619)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.makeAppCrashingLocked(AppErrors.java:477)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner(AppErrors.java:353)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication(AppErrors.java:305)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:13476)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
03-26 11:07:16.214 1574-1986/system_process I/ActivityManager: Restarting because process died: ActivityRecord{57c1c35 u0 com.example.anna.eduback2/.views.Mains.MainActivityProfessor t29}
03-26 11:07:16.237 1574-1986/system_process W/ActivityManager: Exception when starting activity com.example.anna.eduback2/.views.Mains.MainActivityProfessor
                                                               android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
                                                                   at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:884)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1309)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startSpecificActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1408)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityInnerLocked(ActivityStack.java:2548)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityUncheckedLocked(ActivityStack.java:2127)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeFocusedStackTopActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1833)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeFocusedStackTopActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1823)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:1196)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3523)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3359)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1855)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.handleAppCrashLocked(AppErrors.java:619)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.makeAppCrashingLocked(AppErrors.java:477)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner(AppErrors.java:353)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication(AppErrors.java:305)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:13476)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
03-26 11:07:16.237 1574-1986/system_process D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 890
03-26 11:07:16.244 1574-1986/system_process W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{57c1c35 u0 com.example.anna.eduback2/.views.Mains.MainActivityProfessor t29}: app died, no saved state
03-26 11:07:16.269 1574-1986/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc 1991:com.example.anna.eduback2/u0a71 for activity com.example.anna.eduback2/.views.Mains.MainActivityProfessor
03-26 11:07:16.269 1991-1991/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-26 11:07:16.269 1991-1991/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
03-26 11:07:16.270 1574-32531/system_process W/ActivityManager: Spurious death for ProcessRecord{e80098 1991:com.example.anna.eduback2/u0a71}, curProc for 890: null
03-26 11:07:16.270 1574-1986/system_process E/NativeCrashListener: Unable to report native crash
                                                                   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3375)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1855)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.handleAppCrashLocked(AppErrors.java:619)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.makeAppCrashingLocked(AppErrors.java:477)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner(AppErrors.java:353)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication(AppErrors.java:305)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:13476)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
```

Comment: what does the app do

Comment: the app starts with a log in, then you get to the mainpage, here you can push the subject button and go to the SubjectListAcitivty (and the app crash). On the subject¨List page it reads from the database which subjects the professor has added, and shows them in a listview. You can also add new subjects to the list (and save them in the database). This works fine in regular run mode, but not i debug mode. I am working on a new activity when you click on the subjects, but are not able to debug it because i can't even go to the SucjectListActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer: [Android app crashes when launched in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618803/android-app-crashes-when-launched-in-debug-mode).
Try to remove all the breakpoints from nested functions. In Menu go to `Run -> View Breakpoints` and remove the unnecessary breakpoints.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16176910)

Comment: @JigneshAnsodariya The link in question is to a highly upvoted Stackoverflow question, so should not become invalid.

Comment: than add link in comment