# Android studio freezes on debugging with message "SIGNAL = SIGABRT (signal SIGABRT)"

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, sigabrt

My app runs perfectly with no problems. But when I try to debug it, android studio freezes. So I get the message "Waiting for debugger" and then that message goes away and next I get only a black screen in the emulator. 
   I also get the message

```
SIGNAL = SIGABRT (signal SIGABRT)
```

in the debug window under variables tab.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've just started seeing the same issue.

Comment: @TomH.  I was running the code on an emulator. I switched to a real phone and the problem went away. I also deleted my local copy and cloned the git repo again.

Comment: This problem is discussed in following thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618803/android-app-crashes-when-launched-in-debug-mode

Answer (score 3):

I had been facing same problem for some time. I got to know that the fix is very simple. Disable instant run.
Go to "File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run" and disable the instant run.
Please try out this.