# Debugger crashes when debugging a multithread application

Tags: java, android, multithreading, debugging, android-asynctask

I have an Activity, and inside activity class, I have AsyncTask.
There I have this:

```
// inside AsyncTask, inside doInBackground
LoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // some code ...
            }
        });
```

When i try to place breakpoints both inside `run()` function and other AsyncTask code, application is crashing. Crash appears only when debugging, not when just running. When I remove breakpoints from the `run()` function, then it works, but why can't I have breakpoints both in `run()` function and other AsyncTasks elements?

This is what I got in debugger console:
(it was too long to post it there... so i cut off some part)

```
A/art: art/runtime/jdwp/jdwp_event.cc:661] Check failed: Thread::Current() != GetDebugThread() (Thread::Current()=0xaec89400, GetDebugThread()=0xaec89400) Expected event thread
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Runtime aborting...
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Aborting thread:
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "JDWP" prio=5 tid=4 WaitingForDebuggerSend
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cc39d0 self=0xaec89400
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=21856 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaa252920
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=2 core=1 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xaa156000-0xaa158000 stackSize=1014KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 00572f1e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+238)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0053f30e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+526)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0053c30b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+75)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 00527f13  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+67)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 00527ce7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+615)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 0051822b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+155)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0011a5b3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD1Ev+1747)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 0039b74d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEy+733)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0039acf3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEy+211)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 003a0ec9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1705)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 001c2a85  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+53)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 001689fc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+1116)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 001683e9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+1865)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #13 pc 0016979b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+1163)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #14 pc 005a7a7a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache12ResolveClassEPKcPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderE+186)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #15 pc 005a742d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache4FromEPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEPKcb+701)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #16 pc 005a70fd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache14FromDescriptorEPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEPKcb+77)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #17 pc 005862ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier26ResolveClassAndCheckAccessEj+173)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #18 pc 0058840f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier25CodeFlowVerifyInstructionEPj+6463)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #19 pc 00585f96  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier20CodeFlowVerifyMethodEv+358)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #20 pc 00581c9d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier14VerifyCodeFlowEv+973)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #21 pc 0057da56  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier6VerifyEv+854)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #22 pc 0057c742  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier12VerifyMethodEPNS_6ThreadEjPKNS_7DexFileENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS7_INS8_11ClassLoaderEEEPKNS4_8ClassDefEPKNS4_8CodeItemEPNS_9ArtMethodEjPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEbPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSO_11char_traitsIcEENSO_9allocatorIcEEEE+226)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #23 pc 0057c1c7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier13VerifyMethodsILb0EEENS1_11FailureDataEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_11ClassLinkerEPKNS_7DexFileEPKNS8_8ClassDefEPNS_21ClassDataItemIteratorENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENSG_INSH_11ClassLoaderEEEPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEbPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSP_11char_traitsIcEENSP_9allocatorIcEEEE+791)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #24 pc 0057b1f9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFileENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS7_INS8_11ClassLoaderEEEPKNS4_8ClassDefEPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSJ_11char_traitsIcEENSJ_9allocatorIcEEEE+921)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #25 pc 0057a4b9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror5ClassEPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSA_11char_traitsIcEENSA_9allocatorIcEEEE+841)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #26 pc 00174386  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEENS_11LogSeverityE+2102)

// .....

A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "ReferenceQueueDaemon" prio=5 tid=9 Waiting
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cc3a60 self=0xa153d200
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=21857 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaa153920
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xaa051000-0xaa053000 stackSize=1038KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xcd/0x113
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait+0xc5/0x197
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_futex+0x9b/0x742
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_futex+0xaf/0xf6
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0001e258  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0011d1de  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+142)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0011d147  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+39)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 004371b9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadExibNS_11ThreadStateE+537)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 004398a3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectExibNS_11ThreadStateE+339)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00451c2f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL11Object_waitEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+95)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 000006dc  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Object_wait__+104)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   - waiting on <0x06abb381> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:150)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   - locked <0x06abb381> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Binder:21849_2" prio=5 tid=10 Native
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cc3e50 self=0xaec8a800
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=21862 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xa418b920
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=1 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xa408f000-0xa4091000 stackSize=1014KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: binder_thread_read+0xba2/0xd6b
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: binder_ioctl+0x2af/0x6c9
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_vfs_ioctl+0x36b/0x418
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_ioctl+0x4a/0x6a
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 00077b8c  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+28)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 000226d7  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+71)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 00047797  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+279)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 0004793a  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+42)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 000481ff  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+95)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0006effe  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android10PoolThread10threadLoopEv+46)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 00012095  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+309)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0007098b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+111)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 00011883  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN13thread_data_t10trampolineEPKS_+259)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 00074fe2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Profile Saver" prio=5 tid=11 Native
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cf6af0 self=0xab00c300
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=21873 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x91b7f920
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0x91a83000-0x91a85000 stackSize=1014KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xcd/0x113
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait+0xc5/0x197
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_futex+0x9b/0x742
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_futex+0xaf/0xf6
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0001e258  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0011d1de  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+142)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0011d147  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+39)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 003c955c  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12ProfileSaver3RunEv+396)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 003cb66a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12ProfileSaver21RunProfileSaverThreadEPv+106)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00074fe2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Thread-3" prio=5 tid=12 Native
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cf6ee0 self=0xa27c2a00
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=21874 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x91a80920
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0x9197e000-0x91980000 stackSize=1038KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: __skb_recv_datagram+0x19b/0x1f5
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: skb_recv_datagram+0x28/0x2a
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: unix_accept+0x48/0xe9
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_accept4+0xfa/0x1b4
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_socketcall+0x1b9/0x1db
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 00077819  /system/lib/libc.so (__accept4+25)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 00000ce3  /system/lib/libnetd_client.so (???)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0001ef17  /system/lib/libc.so (accept4+55)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 0001eed6  /system/lib/libc.so (accept+54)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 00023808  /system/lib/libjavacore.so (???)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0029ab3c  /system/framework/x86/boot-core-libart.oat (Java_libcore_io_Posix_accept__Ljava_io_FileDescriptor_2Ljava_net_SocketAddress_2+168)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native method)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:64)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.system.Os.accept(Os.java:43)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.accept(LocalSocketImpl.java:336)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.net.LocalServerSocket.accept(LocalServerSocket.java:90)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.tools.ir.server.Server$SocketServerThread.run(Server.java:165)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "RenderThread" prio=5 tid=13 Native
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cc3310 self=0x9f1b2a00
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=21876 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x91836920
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=5 stm=26 core=0 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0x9173a000-0x9173c000 stackSize=1014KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_epoll_wait+0x23c/0x2d1
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_epoll_pwait+0x70/0xe1
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe424  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0007790b  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+43)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 00020cb0  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+112)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 00020d0e  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+62)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 00018f1b  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+203)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 00018d84  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+68)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00035408  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+888)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 00012095  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+309)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0007098b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+111)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 00011883  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN13thread_data_t10trampolineEPKS_+259)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 00074fe2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=14 TimedWaiting
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cc33a0 self=0xa27c6b00
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=21875 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x9193b920
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=1 core=1 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0x91839000-0x9183b000 stackSize=1038KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xcd/0x113
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait+0xc5/0x197
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_futex+0x9b/0x742
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_futex+0xaf/0xf6
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe424  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0001e258  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0011d8c8  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable9TimedWaitEPNS_6ThreadExi+200)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 004371dc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadExibNS_11ThreadStateE+572)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 004398a3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectExibNS_11ThreadStateE+339)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 00451c9d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL13Object_waitJIEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectxi+93)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0000083c  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Object_wait__JI+136)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   - waiting on <0x0753e3ac> (a java.lang.Object)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   - locked <0x0753e3ac> (a java.lang.Object)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:201)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:438)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1057)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "hwuiTask1" prio=5 tid=15 Native
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cf6550 self=0xa3ec3e00
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=21877 nice=-2 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x90cff920
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=0 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0x90c03000-0x90c05000 stackSize=1014KB
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xcd/0x113
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait+0xc5/0x197
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_futex+0x9b/0x742
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_futex+0xaf/0xf6
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0001e258  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0007454d  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_cond_wait+125)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0003643b  /system/lib/libhwui.so (???)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 0001202f  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+207)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 0007098b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+111)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00011883  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN13thread_data_t10trampolineEPKS_+259)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 00074fe2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 21856 (JDWP)

    [ 02-11 09:06:49.521  1261: 1261 W/         ]
    debuggerd: handling request: pid=21849 uid=10084 gid=10084 tid=21856
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the debug points and then it should work (put them in another place).

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618803/android-app-crashes-when-launched-in-debug-mode/40667569).

Comment: That was it! Who would have thought that `art/runtime/runtime.cc` refers to the debug break points.