# Why can I run my app but I can't debug it?

Tags: java, android

When I run my app the normal way, everything works fine. The problem is when I debug, the app crashes. This is the error: [Click here to see, please!](https://pastebin.com/Q3M3F5w7)
Do you know what may be causing this?

These are the error's first two lines:

```
A/art: art/runtime/jdwp/jdwp_event.cc:661] Check failed: Thread::Current() != GetDebugThread() (Thread::Current()=0xa5c0a400, GetDebugThread()=0xa5c0a400) Expected event thread
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Runtime aborting...
```

In this code:

```
  Dexter.withActivity(getActivity())
            .withPermissions(
                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 
            ).withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
        @Override public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
```

`).withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {` - this is the line I can't debug!

Comment: Do you get the same when trying to attach a debugger to a simple "Hello World" app? Have you tried on an emulator or a different device?

Comment: @MichaelDodd No, I haven't tried on a new emulator. I don't know why this happened. I just commented my code and now I can't debug

Comment: So you've managed to isolate the bit of code that causes this? Can you edit that block into your question?

Comment: @MichaelDodd Btw, tried on a new emulator and still doesn't work

Comment: @MichaelDodd I mispelled, I'm sorry. I couldn't debug*

Comment: That's ok, I was trying to eliminate the possibility of a device-specific issue. Unfortunately I don't really know any other possibilities off the top of my head

Comment: @MichaelDodd I found the line that I can't debug. See my updated question please!

Comment: Do you have instant run enabled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app crashes when launched in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618803/android-app-crashes-when-launched-in-debug-mode)

Comment: @TimothyWinters Are you talking about `Quick Boot`? If yes, then yeah, it is enabled

Comment: No, I mean Instant Run.  It's at Settings -> Build -> Instant Run.  It causes trouble with debugging sometimes. If it's on, try turning it off.

Comment: @TimothyWinters Yup, that was the problem. Thanks for the help!