# Android Studio IDE - Debugging Step Into/Over Crashing App

Tags: debugging, android-studio-4.2

I'm using Android Studio 4.1.3 in Windows 10, and I'm having problems with debugging.

The app runs ok if not debugging or using Resume Program while debugging, but if try step debug (over, into, out) it crashes.

It occurs with all apps and with all platforms tested (real devices and emulations) and in all lines of code (in first line of onCreate of the MainActivity for example).

Already tried to delete all break points, cleaning the build, but not could find out how to disable Instant Run in this version.

Logcat:

````
04-24 10:50:41.174 24394-24397/com.cormorant.poifinder A/art: art/runtime/jdwp/jdwp_handler.cc:1187] Check failed: modifier_count < 256 (modifier_count=285, 256=256) 
04-24 10:50:41.214 24394-24397/com.cormorant.poifinder A/art: art/runtime/barrier.cc:90] Check failed: count_ == 0 (count_=-1, 0=0) Attempted to destroy barrier with non zero count
04-24 10:50:41.215 24394-24397/com.cormorant.poifinder A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Runtime aborting --- recursively, so no thread-specific detail!
04-24 10:50:41.215 24394-24397/com.cormorant.poifinder A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] 
    
    --------- beginning of crash
04-24 10:50:41.215 24394-24397/com.cormorant.poifinder A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 24397 (JDWP)```

Have anyone any idea? Thanks.
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android app crashes when launched in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618803/android-app-crashes-when-launched-in-debug-mode)

Comment: Hi Thelouras, this doesn't answer, application runs well in debug mode and crash ONLY if  step into/over are used (breakpoints works fine with Resume Program too). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if is really a answer, but...

The problem is somehow related with APIs from 23 (not tested bellow it) through 26. In none of this API the debugging (Step-Into, Over) works, not in emulated devices and not in physical devices.

APIs from 27 works fine.

Note that the APK of application is 23 and debugging with API 23-26 works with Run and breakpoints to get inside methods... just a pain place dozens breakpoints....

Comment: check my answer I was facing same issue if it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/68830233/5370550

Answer (score 0):

[image: img]

- Change `compileSdkVersion` android `targetSdkVersion` lower than 30, like 28 or much lower.
- Then build and debug.

  - It works well.
- After that, you can recover the `compileSdkVersion` android `targetSdkVersion` you have set before.

  - It works well too.