# How to debug an Android app that crashes while the debugger is attaching?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-debug

My app crashes while waiting for the debugger to attach in Android Studio. The debug call stack doesn't make any sense to me. How can I debug this and figure out why it's crashing?

Adding some context...

This is a video game composed of a "launch" activity that displays various game configuration options and then the "game" activity which is a NativeActivity. The launch activity is Kotlin and AndroidX Compose. So there's both SDK and NDK code.

If I just "Debug App" it will crash with a stack trace similar to the one below. The exact stack trace does seem to vary a bit because it's a timing issue, but it's similar calls.

I can't identify the thread that's crashing but it's not the Main UI thread because I can put a breakpoint on the launch activity's "create" method and it will trip, then crash after continuing.

This is the call stack of the errant thread at the time of crash on a Pixel 8 Pro.

```
openjdkjvmti::ThreadUtil::GetNativeThread(_jobject *, const art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable &, art::Thread **, jvmtiError *) 0x000000710fce06d8
openjdkjvmti::ThreadUtil::GetThreadLocalStorage(_jvmtiEnv *, _jobject *, void **) 0x000000710fce39c0
findThread 0x000000710fbdeaa0
threadControl_clearCLEInfo 0x000000710fbe0a94
event_callback 0x000000710fbd61d0
cbThreadStart 0x000000710fbd3320
openjdkjvmti::ThreadCallback::Post<…>(art::Thread *) 0x000000710fcded80
art::Thread::CreateCallback(void *) 0x0000007113f3a0d8
art::Thread::CreateCallbackWithUffdGc(void *) 0x0000007113f39b64
__pthread_start(void *) 0x00000073be361cd0
__start_thread 0x00000073be2f5b04
```

Here's another call stack. Sometimes this one happens instead of the above call stack.

```
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e2978a4
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e29790c
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e2973e0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e2973e0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e297818
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e2973e0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e297818
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e2973e0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e297818
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e2973e0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e297818
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e2973e0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e297818
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e297818
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e297818
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e2973e0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e2973e0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e29828c
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e29828c
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e2973e0
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
art::interpreter::DoCall<…>(art::ArtMethod *, art::Thread *, art::ShadowFrame &, const art::Instruction *, unsigned short, bool, art::JValue *) 0x000000795e311d20
art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<…>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext *) 0x000000795e29828c
ExecuteSwitchImplAsm 0x000000795e157fdc
art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.__uniq.112435418011751916792819755956732575238.llvm.420609892041422114) 0x000000795e174124
artQuickToInterpreterBridge 0x000000795e173a1c
art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge 0x000000795e15596c
art_quick_invoke_stub 0x000000795e13eda8
art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread *, unsigned int *, unsigned int, art::JValue *, const char *) 0x000000795e039d58
art::Thread::CreateCallback(void *) 0x000000795e33a1b4
art::Thread::CreateCallbackWithUffdGc(void *) 0x000000795e339b64
__pthread_start(void *) 0x00000079e8d550f8
__start_thread 0x00000079e8ceea08
```

Comment: Mind sharing the crash stack trace?  Also, try to Restart and Invalidate Cache on Android Studio.

Comment: And some more details on the app would be helpful: what type of project is it (Java/Kotlin/Xamarin,Flutter/...) what native libraries are loaded? What test device do you use (emulator, physical device model and manufacturer). Does this happen on all test devices?

Comment: Updated with more info.

Comment: Maybe this can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618803/android-app-crashes-when-launched-in-debug-mode/58308619#58308619

Comment: Unfortunately my phones the "Wait for debugger" option is grayed out. What does that mean?